# Is there a way to add one element to all pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

So i got some custom created pages on wordpress + and main index template which is my main page.I want to add scroll to top button on all pages.When i add code to main index page it shows only on home page and when i add it to page template file it appears only on posts pages.So is there a way to make code acting on both pages ( i got like 4 more custom pages,just giving example with 2) without copying of the code on each file?Because if i make even more custom pages it will be a lot of code copied and i definetlly don't want that. Thanks :P

Comment: create a shortcode for the button with scroll and add the short code in all pages' front end

Comment: Well your answer is the because it answers my question,but i will choose Andy's answer,because it really can help some peoples which don't know java out.Thanks for respond mate <3 much appreciated

Comment: you are welcomed, then I will create an answer out of my comment so people can see it, please accept it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`footer.php`** and **`header.php`** is used by all pages (normaly). You can put such code in there.

---

The best way to implement a "scroll to top button" is IMO via javascript. The javascript code can check if a "scroll to top button" is suitable, because you don't need it when the content is not to big, or if you actualy on top. And when you scroll down a certain distance, it appears at a fixed position.

### Example (using jQuery):

```js
var scroll_top_button_is_visible = false;
var scroll_distance = 500;

var $scroll_top_button = $('<div class="scroll-top-button">back to top</div>');
// inject the button, so you don't have to create the button in any templates
$scroll_top_button.appendTo('body');

$(window).scroll(function() {
  // called on every scroll action
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > scroll_distance && !scroll_top_button_is_visible) {
    scroll_top_button_is_visible = true;
    $scroll_top_button.fadeIn(200);
  } else if ($(window).scrollTop() < scroll_distance && scroll_top_button_is_visible) {
    scroll_top_button_is_visible = false;
    $scroll_top_button.fadeOut(200);
  }
});

// scroll to top if button is clicked
$('.scroll-top-button').click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: 0
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
p {
  margin-bottom: 300px;
}

.scroll-top-button {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: white;
  background: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <h1>Example of a "Scroll to Top Button"</h1>
  <h2>Scroll down and look what happens</h2>
  <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
   <p>Some content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time mate,i will mark your answer as correct.It didn't really answer can you make button available to all pages without copy the code.I get my answer from Yahya,but you'r answer can really help out to somebody which don't know java.<3 Thanks mate!!

Comment: `footer.php` and `header.php` is a good choice for code that should appear on every page.

Answer (score 1):

create a shortcode for the button with scroll and add the shortcode in all pages' front end